# Node.JS Bot Error SteamGuardMobile

Tags: node.js, bots, steam

I keep getting this error when ever I start Steam Bot.

```
[2016-05-03 03:00:03.184] [DEBUG] [default] - [Error: SteamGuardMobile]
Error: SteamGuardMobile
at SteamCommunity.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\BOTNEW\node_mo
dules\steamcommunity\index.js:128:14)
at Request._callback (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\BOTNEW\node_modules\ste
amcommunity\components\http.js:62:14)
at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\BOTNEW\node_modules
\request\request.js:200:22)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:172:7)
at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\BOTNEW\node_modules\r
equest\request.js:1067:10)
at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\BOTNEW\node_m
odules\request\request.js:988:12)
at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
```

bot.js http://pastebin.com/07uXJgdJ

bot_manager.js http://pastebin.com/RfJbkrQe

Any help would be amazing and if you are looking for anymore information to help me solve this issue just ask, But I am pretty new to Steam Bot's!